# Python 3.9 Import Works in Linux, Not Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows

I am writing an app that needs to work both in Windows and in Linux.  I have been developing it in Linux and am just now working on the details to make it work on both platforms.  The issue I am running into is with regards to importing other python files from another directory.  The app, which runs without issue in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), has the following folder structure:

```
- data
- images
- lib
---- configTools.py
---- dbTools.py
---- osciloscopeTools.py
---- peakFindingTools.py
---- poissonTools.py
---- plottingTools.py
---- spacingTools.py
- src
---- config.py
---- interface.py
```

The program begins with running interface.py.  The beginning of the code that I have at the moment is written as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('../lib')
#sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../lib'))

import platform
import subprocess as subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog, QLabel, QCheckBox, QLineEdit, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
#from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import  QtCore, QtWidgets
import matplotlib
import time
import sqlite3

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import imageio
import csv

# Import local files
import configTools as ct
import dbTools as dbt
import oscilloscopeTools as ot
import peakFindingTools as pft
import poissonTools as pt
import config
import plottingTools as pltools
```

The issue when running in Windows (Visual Studio 2019) is the block at the bottom where I attempt to import my other python files.  An exception is thrown saying "No module named 'configTools'".    All of the files in that block are similarly underlined in the IDE, saying "unresolved import ___" where ___ is the filename of each.  My best guess is that the line executing "sys.path.append('../lib')" is not accomplishing the desired effects in Windows.  Permanently altering environment variables is not a good option for me since this app needs to be portable once it's done.  It works fine in Linux, so I am under the impression that this is valid Python, but I cannot find the correct way to accomplish the task at hand in Windows.  Further, I really do not want to put everything in the same folder; even if that would be the easiest thing for the python files, the data and images folders will populate with hundreds of files over the course of execution, and I suspect that I will run into similar problems when trying to read and write from those folders.

Comment: Are you sure when you run interface.py, you have `src` as the current directory ?

Comment: I am not sure; I am pretty new to Visual Studio.  Do you know how I change that?  I assumed that all paths referenced within a file were relative to that file's location unless the filepath was absolute.

Comment: No, it's relative to the current process. Try `sys.path.append('lib')`

Comment: That did the trick!  Do you know if all IDEs will act the same in that regard?  If I hand this off to someone else and they aren't running Visual Studio, will they behave the same?  With this revelation, I am now trying to figure out how to best write this for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: It should work as long as you run the program in the parent directory of `lib`, which is most IDE do.